# Dell laptop, dell dock, will only give me 1 or 3 active displays

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, dell, gpu-driver

I have a Latitude E5570, and a Dell dock with 2 displays attached. I am running a fresh install of 18.10. With my laptop lid closed, only the "#3" display is recognized. When I open the laptop lid, all 3 displays work. Since all 3 work, I would assume the video driver is working. Any thoughts?

Comment: Similar for me but I move my mouse to where the other screens are and they turn on.